# Lazy fetching + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following relationships: User - Role - Permission, they are many-to-many relationships. I am using lazy fetching of Hibernate to collect User's authorities, and Spring Security's @PreAuthorize annotation for checking permissions at the endpoints. At every endpoint it works, except at one of them (here I get LazyInitializationException). What could be the problem?

Endpoint in Controller:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_READ_PRIVILEGE')")
    @GetMapping("getRoles")
    public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> getRoles (...) {..}
```

Defining User-Role relationship in User Entity:

```
@JsonBackReference
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
      CascadeType.PERSIST
  })
  @JoinTable(
      name = "role_user",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> roles;
```

Defining User-Role relationship in Role Entity:

```
@JsonManagedReference
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<User> users;
```

Collecting authorities in UserDetails implementation:
(First I've tried to work with dependency injection, and a query with "join fetch" in repository layer, but for some reason dependency injection didn't work in this implementation, I've always got NullPointerException.)

```
@Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    user.getRoles().forEach(
        getRolesAndPermissions(authorities)
    );

    user.getGroups().forEach(
        group -> group.getRoles().forEach(
            getRolesAndPermissions(authorities)
        )
    );

    return authorities;
  }

  private Consumer<Role> getRolesAndPermissions(List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return role -> {
      authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleNameSpringFormat()));
      role.getPermissions().forEach(
          permission -> {
            if (!authorities.contains(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    permission.getPermissionNameSpringFormat().toString()))) {
              authorities.add(
                  new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                      permission.getPermissionNameSpringFormat().toString()));
            }
          }
      );
    };
  }
```

Comment: Transaction setup?

Comment: I've tried to use the @Transactional annotation here, but it didn't work.